# Is it possible to access all properties of an object using id?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have an Object: aObject, it has properties a,b,c.

I can access the properties using:

```
aObject.a

aObject.b

aObject.c
```

Is it possible to access all properties of the object using id? such as

```
[aObject indexOf:0]
[aObject indexOf:1]
[aObject indexOf:2]
```

or something likes that.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVC (Key Value Coding) will allow you to set values of properties using the method `[anObject setValue:aValue forKey:@"a"]`.

If you truly want to iterate through each property, setting its value, then you will need to drop down to the objective-c runtime.

```
unsigned int outCount, i;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([anObject class], &outCount);
for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    const char * name = property_getName(property);

    [anObject setValue:anyValue forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]];
}
free(properties);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if I never used it, it seems it's possible with [class_copyPropertyList](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_copyPropertyList) method.